# TFS 2015 Build Definitions

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

We have a project that creates and edits pdfs on the file system. When we fire a tfs build, it deletes the generated pdfs in the folder (and we need them to stay). Is there a way to tell the build to exclude deleting the pdf's that are in the folder every time we do a deployment?

Answer (score 0):

i was a google click away - sorry. the answer was in msbuild arguments. /p:DeleteExistingFiles=False 
/p:SkipExtraFilesOnServer=True 
/p:ReplaceMatchingFiles=True